# How to append date to the filename for logging

Tags: r

I'm currently triggering an R script via a scheduler. Sometimes the R script causes errors (maybe due to input problmens). After each run, I get an r-out file with the history log. That log is super helpful in checking if everything went as planed but unfortunately it gets overwritten every day. My question now is: how can I get a different r-out file each day (e.g. with the date to it)

Best regards and thank you,
Phil

Comment: got some code for us? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Consider adding a code that could help us reproduce the error.

Comment: yes, rHertel. The code is not the issue here rather how to get my console output for each run since it is triggered remotely. I like your answer from below but how do I fill my console output into it?

Comment: Maybe take a look  at `?sink`. There are different ways to redirect the standard output to a file. This could be done either on the OS level or with the R script. In order to help in this case it would be good to know how the log file is generated. I was assuming that it was written by the R script.

Answer (score 3):

To generate a filename that includes the current date, you could take the output of `Sys.Date()` and use `paste0`to compose the name of the file including the date.

Maybe something like this:

```
filename <- paste0("R-out_", Sys.Date(), ".log")
#> filename
#[1] "R-out_2016-08-24.log"
```

The format of the date can be changed with `format()` if this is desired (Thanks to @Konrad for reminding this). For instance, we could use `format(Sys.Date(), "%d-%m-%Y")` to obtain the day-month-year form that is typically used, e.g., in Europe:

```
filename <- paste0("R-out_", format(Sys.Date(), "%d-%m-%Y"), ".log")
```

---

We can use `sink()`to redirect the console (standard) output of a script to a file. In this case the script could be edited to include a definition of the `filename` as described above, followed by the command

```
sink(filename)
```

This should be inserted into the script file before anything is displayed in the standard output. Possibly these two lines (the definition of the filename and the sink command) could be placed at the very beginning, but I would recommend using `setwd(<pathToMyOutputDirectory>)` first, to specify the output directory. After the `sink(filename)` command, any output that would normally be displayed in the console will be stored in the file called according to the character string stored in `filename`. At the end of the script it would be good to restore the default setting for the standard output by using `sink()` without any parameter (or, equivalently, `sink(file = NULL)`).

Comment: Just wanted to add that it may be useful to encapsulate `Sys.Date()` call in `format()` to be consistent with the use of `_` sign in the name: `format(Sys.Date(), "%d_%m_%y")`.

Comment: I would also recomend using the ISO 8601 date standard (fmt = "%Y-%m-%d"), because then your files will be ordered by date and easier to find. Less headaches in the long term.

Comment: the script is triggered via a batch file (which again is triggered via a scheduler). Within the script there is no command that creates the r.out file hence it is done by the batch file but I don't know how to adjust it within the batch file